# Perl's side of "for i in `cat file` do echo $i

Tags: perl, bash, foreach

In bash we have:

```
for i in `cat file` ; do
#do something here for example
echo $i    
done;
```

How can I do that in a perl script?

I tried it with

```
#! /usr/bin/perl  
use warnings; 
use strict;  
my $lines; 
while (<>) {   $lines .= $_ if 3 .. 5; } continue {   close ARGV if eof; }  

print $lines;
```

but it does not loop through them; it prints all lines from file on first run.

Thank you.

*EDIT:* Yes, but it still does not loop through them; the script takes all variables and if for example I have

```
print "Header here\n";  
print $lines;  
print "Footer here\n\n";
```

and my variables file contains

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
etc...
```

it prints:

```
Header here
line1
line2
line3
line4 etc..
Footer here
```

instead of

```
Header here
line1
Footer here 

Header here
line2
Footer here 

Header here
line3
Footer here 

Header here
line4
Footer here 

etc...
```

Comment: You are doing different things in your perl script than your bash script; do you really want the perl script to do just what the bash script does?  If so, you've got a lot of extra stuff added that is confusing the issue.  If *not*, please show how you want to invoke the perl script, sample input, and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying again:

Replace your `$lines .= $_` with `push @lines, $_`.

Then where you print, do:

```
for (@lines) {
    print "Header here\n";
    print $_;
    print "Footer here\n\n";
}
```

instead of printing $lines, etc.

Though it sounds like you don't want the stuff selecting only lines 3 through 5; if that's the case, your whole program should just be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<>) {
    print "Header here\n";
    print $_;
    print "Footer here\n\n";
}
```

Comment: No, that's not right.   <> assumes @ARGV contains filenames, concatenates them all and spins through their contents  line by line (actually, "record by record" in this case).

Comment: @masonk: I was guessing that might be what was wanted; now I see it's not.

Comment: #! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $lines;
while (<>) {
push @lines, $_ if 3 .. 5;
}
for (@lines) {
print "Header here\n";
print $lines;
print "Footer here\n\n";
}
Like ThIS?

Comment: it gives Global symbol "@lines" requires explicit package name at ./pers line 6,8 10

Answer (score 1):

1. You're taking <> apart and then immediately putting it back together with the .= concatenate operator.  If you want to do something to each line, such as print a header or footer, then you do it inside the loop.
2. It's possible that your input record separator is wrong and <> is not really going through multiple times.  Print something *inside* the loop, such as ++$count, to see how many times you actually entered the loop.  You might have to change your IRS, which is the $/ variable.

Comment: i'm beginner , dont really get what u saying.. sry

Comment: 3..5 is only true on lines 3 to 5.  The flip flop operator behaves differently if the parameter is a scalar. See perlop

Comment: 1.  Operators don't take parameters.  They take operands.  2. The .. char sequence is only the flip flop operator in scalar context; it is the range constructor operator in list context.  3. The expression 3 .. 5 is in scalar context in the OP.  4. I didn't understand your comment.  5.  But I did read perldoc perlop, and found the following that explains it well: `If either operand of scalar ".." is a constant expression, that operand is considered true if it is equal ("==") to the current input line number (the $.
       variable).`  Thanks for the tip!  Removing my first point.

Answer (score 1):

Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read i ; do
    echo $i
done < file
```

Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
open(my $fh, '<', 'file') or die $!;
while (my $i = <$fh>){
    print $i;
}
close($fh) or die $!;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your after. But if I wanted to achieve the same in Perl on stdin, as you have in your `bash` script I would do something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while(<>)
{
   # Do something to $_ e.g. print lines 3 through 5
   print if 3 .. 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash:

```
for i in `cat file` ; do
#do something here for example
echo $i    
done;
```

Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

while (<>) {
  print $_;
}
```

[man perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for more information on the $_ variable